# Using in_array within elequent call

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I can make the following call

```
$userGroups = Auth::user()->getGroups();
```

The above will output something like the following

```
array:10 [▼
  0 => "Admin"
  1 => "TeamA"
  3 => "USA"
  4 => "security"
  9 => "Users"
]
```

So I can see that I am a member of all of the above groups.  I also have a clients table, and one of the fields of this table is team.  An example client is like so

```
#attributes: array:11 [▼
    "id" => "3"
    "clientName" => "Some Client"
    "contactEmail" => ""
    "team" => "TeamA"
    "created_at" => "2016-07-04 15:08:15"
    "updated_at" => "2016-07-04 15:08:15"
]
```

What I am trying to do is get all clients which have a team which is part of the logged in users groups.  So you can see that I am apart of TeamA therefor I want all
clients that have a team value of TeamA.  I was thinking something along the lines of this

```
$clients =  Client::where('team', in_array('TeamA', $userGroups))->get();
```

The above returns an empty result set, but hopefully it demonstrates what I am after.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like that should use a `->whereIn()` eloquent clause. Check out the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as if you are looking for [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses)?:

```
$clients = Client::whereIn('team', $userGroups)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo!

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was after.  One thing though, you have done the arrow after the ::  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want a simple "where"?

```
$clients =  Client::where('team', 'TeamA')->get();
```

You will get all clients, that have a team of "TeamA".

If you want to get all clients for multiple groups, use "whereIn":

```
$clients =  Client::whereIn('team', $userGroups)->get();
```